# CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView returns null just after SetBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have some code in a constructor for a WPF UserControl. Basically I set a binding to an XmlDataProvider (my data is dynamic). I then want to set the CustomSort on the view to be a MySorter (implementing IComparer).

The problem is that GetDefaultView returns null if called directly after the SetBinding call - as though there is some asynchronous processing going on to set up the ItemsSource. Note that if I call the same GetDefaultView code later in a button Click handler it works fine, it doesn't return null and the sort mechanism all works fine and dandy.

```
MyListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);

ListCollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyListBox.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView;

view.CustomSort = new MySorter(); // falls over - view is null
```

My question is, why does GetDefaultView return null when called directly after SetBinding, is there an event I need to wait for before I call GetDefaultView and get a non-null response?

Comment: It might help to know where this code is? Perhaps the binding itself is `null` at this point.

Comment: I made a typo in my original post (now corrected), sorry. The Users.ItemsSource in the GetDefaultView is actually the same MyListBox that has the binding set in the first line. Hence why the MyListBox.ItemsSource should be non-null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your `Users.ItemsSource` an `ItemCollection`? Then probably view would be an [`ItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx) too because it inherits from [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx).

`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` returns an `ICollectionView`. There are more classes which inherit from `CollectionView` then `ListCollectionView` only. Make sure your cast doesn't fail, e.g. with this code:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Users.ItemsSource);
Console.WriteLine(view.GetType());
```

Comment: I made a typo in my original post (now corrected), sorry. The Users.ItemsSource in the GetDefaultView is actually the same MyListBox that has the binding set in the first line. Hence why the MyListBox.ItemsSource should be non-null. The cast doesn't fail when called in a later Click event handler so I don't think it's a casting issue. Thanks.

Comment: What is my code (with correction) showing?. Check in this order if MyListBox.ItemsSource is Null and if CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyListBox.ItemsSource) is Null.

Comment: MyListBox.ItemsSource is null... However it is non-null in a button Click handler just after - as if it hadn't finished binding when it returned from the SetBinding call? There is a fair amount of data in the XmlDataProvider but it still populates in less than a second.

Comment: Try getting DefaultView from your binding source collection directly  instead of MyListBox.ItemsSource.

Comment: CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(binding.Source) also returns null, although looking in the debugger binding.Source _is_ set to my XmlDataProvider which in turn does appear to be populated (it's document member shows the XML in it's InnerXml member).

Comment: No, I meant you are setting the binding.Source to your XmlDataProvider and should try getting the DefaultView from **this source** directly. Something like `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(YourDataProviderCollection)`.

Comment: Ah, ok... CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyXmlDataProvider) also returns null. I just noticed an IsAsynchronous flag on my data provider that is set to true, setting this to false doesn't seem to resolve the issue however, GetDefaultView still returns null with the data provider and the ListBox.ItemsSource specified.

Comment: You have to wait until the DataProvider has the data. Probably there is an event for data loaded or (I think not so good) you could subscribe to [ListBox.SourceUpdated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sourceupdated).

Comment: I added a DataChanged handler from the data provider which gets called twice, the first call producing a null from GetDefaultView and the second producing non-null - which allows me to set the CustomSort and answers this question. So marking as answer, thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Even though it executes my IComparer and runs through the sort process in the DataChanged event processing it doesn't update the ListBox display so I'm still scratching my head. The same code in the button handler causes the sort to execute and the list box to update. Must be something different about the context that the handlers run in, very strange ... but a different question.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when XmlDataProvider is used. GetDefaultView does not return null when DataContext is set from an object instance from code. However when used XmlDataProvider, GetDefaultView returns null. I found that is because until the xml is loaded it returns null.

Therefore if the CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView is called from with event handler method of "Loaded" event, it works fine.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.comboBox1.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ComboBoxLoaded);           
    }

    private void ComboBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((XmlDataProvider)this.myGrid.DataContext).Data);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Location", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }
```

You can find this example following this link (under stage 8):

http://wpfgrid.blogspot.com/2013/01/simple-combobox-implementation.html

Comment: We had seen random occasions where 'CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView' would return 'null' but could not understand why. I think this is the answer.